# Integer-Binary-Hexa Converter in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am coding a converter in C# to convert from integer, binary and hexadecimal into same formats. Of course the input format and the output format is given. 
Another interesting point is that my input is a `string` and my output is also a `string`.

So, now I wonder if there is a way to do all those conversions using the same function because in all questions I explored some solutions are given for only one of my 6 cases and I don't find it really elegant.

To summarize:

```
Input String | Output String
-------------|--------------
int32        | hexa
int32        | binary
binary       | int32
binary       | hexa
hexa         | int32
hexa         | binary
```

**EDIT:** All exceptions will be handled with try-catch if necessary.

Comment: What do you mean 'in one function'? If you want to get different conversions you should make each one its own function.

Comment: Yes but I would like to use the same method like `Convert.toString(inputType, inputValue, outputType)` instead of having to deal with multiple tricks to convert from one type to another.

Comment: It seems you're looking for this but in C#: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a two-step process: parsing a string from one of the three formats, and then convert to one of the three formats.

To parse, you can use the respective `Parse` (or `TryParse` if you want to avoid exceptions) methods which exist for the different numeric types. On integer types, you can use the `NumberStyles.HexNumber` to parse from a hex number.

To convert to a string, use the overloaded `ToString` with the appropriate culture and format.

Note that you can do type conversions through the `IConvertible` interface, which is supported by all native number types.

Here's some pseudocode (**will not compile** but should illustrate the points made):

```
enum NumberKind {
  Int32,
  Decimal,
  Hexa
}

string ConvertNumber(NumberKind inputKind, string inputValue, NumberKind outputKind) {
  IConvertible intermediate;
  switch (inputKind) {
  case NumberKind.Int32:
    intermediate = Int32.Parse(inputValue, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    break;
  case NumberKind.Decimal:
    intermediate = Decimal.Parse(inputValue, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    break;
  case NumberKind.Hexa:
    intermediate = Int32.Parse(inputValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    break;
  }
  switch (outputKind) {
  case NumberKind.Int32:
    return intermediate.ToInt32().ToString("D", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  case NumberKind.Decimal:
    return intermediate.ToDecimal().ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  case NumberKind.Hexa:
    return intermediate.ToInt32().ToString("X", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, you formalised the philosophy I am looking for. I edited my question because I wrote `decimal` instead of `binary`, however your answer is perfect.

Comment: I implemented my converter perfectly with this solution, I would just add that one has to use `using System.Globalization;` in order to use NumberStyles.